# No such file or directory: 'nmap': 'nmap'

Tags: python, networking

> The plan is to check for open ports and i am having an error of nmap even though the library is already installed and i am using anacond

```
import socket, subprocess, re

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
nmap_lst_out = []

s = socket.socket()
print ('The Name of the Local Machine:-',host)
print ('\n' * 2)
print ('*' * 60)
print('PLEASE WAIT SCANNING THE REMOTE HOST {} AT {}'.format(host,socket.gethostbyname('localhost')))
print ('*' * 60)
for port in range(1,1024):
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
        open_port = socket.getservbyport(port)
        print ('PORT {0} OPEN'.format(open_port))
        s.close()
        s = socket.socket()

    except:
        print ("\r+",end="")


nmap_out = subprocess.check_output(['nmap','Saujan'])
nmap_out = str(nmap_out)
nmap_out = nmap_out.split('\\n')

for i in nmap_out:
    out = re.search('(open\s+)([a-zA-Z]+)',i)
    if out:
       nmap_lst_out.append(out.group(2))
       print ('NMAP OPEN PORT:-',out.group(2))`
```

I have already installed the package as well.

> Package already installed

Saujan:Project Saujan$ pip install nmap
Requirement already satisfied: nmap in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)

Comment: Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nmap': 'nmap'

This is the error i am getting

Comment: `nmap_out=subprocess.check_output(['nmap','Saujan'])` you are calling the external program `nmap` not the python package. do you have nmap installed? is it in your `PATH` variable? open a shell and run nmap, does it work?

Comment: Hi Nullman yes it is installed

Comment: what about my other questions? also, did you try with `shell=True` in the subprocess? most probably you need to provide the full path to your `nmap` program

Comment: did this fix the problem? I ran the code above and other than the last parentheses it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have nmap installed, you can't execute it as long as you don't run it in the path directory. So first you should navigate to the directory in which nmap is installed, and THEN try running it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if Nmap is installed on your computer, not in your Python packages. It depends on your operating system, but try:

- `apt-get install nmap` - For debian-based like Debian, Ubuntu, etc...
- `yum install nmap` - For Centos/RedHat distributions.
- `brew install nmap` - On MacOS
- Install the application by downloading the installer on Windows systems

2. It is better if you use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.check_output`:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', 'Saujan'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
for i in output.readlines():
    # Use your regular expressions...
```

3. Additionally, there are libraries that may do that work for you. I'm the author of one called [Nmapthon](https://nmapthon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Feel free to check it out